# LaTeX | hyperref error | Argument of � has an extra }. \end{document}

Tags: latex, pdflatex, hyperref

I got a new PC with Windows 10 Pro operating system several days ago and decided to install **TeXstudio + MiKTeX**.

And I faced a problem compiling LaTeX file. The problem is when I try to add `\usepackage{hyperref}` or code stuff similar to this line (more detailed in the code with the comment line `% problem is here if I add this line`) I get an error which says: `Argument of � has an extra }. \end{document}`.

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{floatrow,calc}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hspace{3cm}}
\thisfloatsetup{floatrowsep=mysep}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .png, .jpg}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Black}{rgb}{0,0,0}

\usepackage[unicode, colorlinks, linkcolor=Black]{hyperref} % problem is here if I add this line
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{linkcolor}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{urlcolor}{HTML}{000000}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH, linkcolor=linkcolor, urlcolor=urlcolor, colorlinks=True} % problem is here if I add this line
\fontfamily{ptm}
\parindent=1cm
\sloppy
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{hyperref} % problem is here if I add this line

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{epigraph} %%% to make inspirational quotes.

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

Random text
    
${\mathcal {E}}=-{{d\Phi_{B}} \over dt},$ where

${\mathcal {E}}$ — random letter.   

\end{document}
```

**Error I get:**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxDX7.png)

When I try this code in **OverLeaf** or on **my notebook** or **without hyperref packages** - **everything's fine**. But I need this package if, for example, I'll have to add references...

Did someone face similar problem? Maybe I need to install some other packages?

Comment: Please post your code block without line numbers, so we copy and paste it to test

Comment: That being said, you shouldn't load hyperref in line 34, you already load it with different options in line 25 (which is a bit early, you should load it as one of last packages)

Comment: I loaded it one of the last packages... Nothing has changed...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[A quote from the hyperref maintainer](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/833#issuecomment-1140498082):

> But I would recommend to drop utf8x/ucs. Most improvements in the handling of utf8 which e.g. allow you to use them in \labels and filenames are undone by utf8x/ucs.

If the `ucs` package and `utf8x` inputenc option is removed, your code compiles.

---

- Furthermore you should remove the `pdftex` from `graphicx`. It will automatically choose the best suited option to match your compilation chain.
- You should also not load the same package multiple times, in particular not with different options
- And load `hyperref` after the other packages (there are only very view exceptions)
- No need to load `color` if you also load `xcolor`

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{floatrow,calc}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hspace{3cm}}
\thisfloatsetup{floatrowsep=mysep}
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[
%pdftex
]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .png, .jpg}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Black}{rgb}{0,0,0}

\fontfamily{ptm}
\parindent=1cm
\sloppy
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % problem is here if I add this line

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{epigraph} %%% to make inspirational quotes.

\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[unicode, colorlinks, linkcolor=Black]{hyperref} % problem is here if I add this line

\definecolor{linkcolor}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{urlcolor}{HTML}{000000}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH, linkcolor=linkcolor, urlcolor=urlcolor, colorlinks=True} % problem is here if I add this line


\begin{document}

Random text
    
${\mathcal {E}}=-\frac{{d\Phi_{B}} }{ dt},$ where

${\mathcal {E}}$ — random letter.   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot - I opened an old latex file to do some minor changes, and was baffled by the file not compiling, even though I know it compiled last time (3 years ago). Life saver :)

Comment: How to be about unicode characters without the `inputenc` package?

Comment: @Cornul11 utf8 is the default input encoding in latex since sometime about 2018.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, funny you say that since I cannot compile a project with pdflatex because it is complaining about some Unicode characters. I had to switch to XeLaTeX to fix this issue.

Comment: @Cornul11 Can you make a minimal working example?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem. I changed the **Tex Live Version** to **2021** and it was resolved. (Initially, it was 2022 in my setting. Setting can be found on **Menu** option at the top-left corner)